# Integrating External JQUERY code with Edge Animate (Edge animate runs on JQUERY Backbone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, adobe-edge

There are two ways I can see of integrating Edge Animate With External JQuery

Something happens within Adobe Edge and triggers something to happen externally or vice versa.....

1. When an action is performed (`mouseUp`, `MouseOver`... etc...) we can initiate some external Jquery**

   ***For example:***

   When I **`mouseUp`** my play button I run the function  `playPause()` and my audio starts to play

   ```
   function playPause(){
       if( $("#liveStream").data("jPlayer").status.paused ) {
           $("#liveStream").jPlayer("play");
       }
       else {
           $("#liveStream").jPlayer("pause");
       }
   }
   ```

   So this is fine... I perform an action in Adobe Edge and something external to the composition occurs, in this case it connects to a live stream of audio and the user gets the desired result.
2. When an event occurs in external Jquery (playing, connection lost, audio not ready... etc...) we can perform an action within Adobe Edge**

   ***For example:***

   When the audio stream is playing and the user is definitely hearing music i need to perform an action within Adobe Edge like `sym.$("playButton").hide();` which hides the play button because obviously there is no need to click play anymore when the music is already playing..

   This is were my Jquery understanding ends..

**Questions:**

1. Where do I put global code within my Adobe Edge composition that triggers actions when external jQuery returns an event
2. How do I go about coding this...

Below is my best attempt

```
function playStatus(){
        $("#liveStream").bind($.jPlayer.event.playing, function (event) {
            sym.$("playButton").hide();
        });
    }
```

Now my attempt is probably way off the truth but I'm hoping you understand what I am trying to achieve..

I'm pretty sure I should not be coding an **if/else** statement because an **event** is not a **variable**, an **event** fires once and then I write the code to handle the **event** when it fires...